# Using JSON module to encode an object in Python

Tags: python, json

I have this String that I need to pass into a REST request

```
{"notification":{"tag":"MyTag"}}
```

I'm trying to turn into an object using the JSON module in python.

This is my attempt so far

```
import json
obj = json.dumps([{'notification': ('{tag : MyTag}')}])
```

But it isn't parsed correctly so the REST request won't work. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just dump your dictionary *as is*, replace:

```
obj = json.dumps([{'notification': ('{tag : MyTag}')}])
```

with:

```
obj = json.dumps({"notification": {"tag": "MyTag"}})
```

Comment: but is there a more elegant way to do this without handwriting out the entire string? Perhaps some key-value way?

Comment: @sraval well, you can just use the variable pointing to your object: `obj_string = json.dumps(obj)`.